# Dragged all controls on swift storyboard down from screen top but when run they are back at top of screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've tried dragging all the controls at once or singly from top of screen in storboard down to lower half of screen.   But when I run it they all are at top of iphone screen.

I have iPhone 10 and selected iPhone 11 in xcode.

pict shows after I dragged them all downward.

(also, what's that smaller image of the screen in the upper right?  When I hover mouse over it, no information; just Mickey Mouse hand (I guess for while there Steve Jobs owned Disney))

[image]

[This is the complete project from github <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<](https://github.com/anoop4real/SocketSwiftSample)

Answer (score 1):

Your storyboard uses autolayout. That means that the positions / sizes of views are determined by their *constraints*.

Dragging views around physically on the canvas has no ultimate effect, except that now, because your apparent positions do not match the position at runtime, you get a "misplaced views" warning (which you are apparently ignoring or you wouldn't be asking this question).

> also, what's that smaller image of the screen in the upper

That's the Minimap.

Comment: matt: Thanks for explanation.  Good-bye, autolayout.